# How to configure Ethernet interface with gateway IP address?

Tags: unix, networking, ip, ethernet

I have been asked to the following on a sample Unix server:

Configure eth1 to xxx.xx.xx.xxx/24 with gateway IP Address of: xxx.xx.xx.x

Any help would be welcome as I am a relative novice when it comes networking with Unix.

Comment: Welcome to Unix, StackOverflow is for questions about programming, not system configuration. SuperUser.com would have been more a more appropriate  site for your question.

Comment: Thanks, i'll bear that in mind in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `route` command is what you want, something like this:

```
route add -net 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.3.10
```

This only adds it until networking is restarted or the machine is rebooted, so you will need to find where to add static routes like `/etc/sysconfig/static-routes` to add it permanently.